Spring Boot pagination with @ManyToMany relationship by the child table
I have the following model:
@Entity
@Builder
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "forecast")
public class ForecastModel implements Serializable {

  @Serial private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  @UuidGenerator
  @package.common.hibernate.constraint.UUID
  private UUID id;

  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinTable(
      name = "forecast_item",
      joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "forecast_id"),
      inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "item_id"))
  @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<ItemModel> item;
}

Unfortunatelly and I don't know why the relationship is not mapped in ItemModel class, I would have:
@Entity
@Builder
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "item")
public class ItemModel implements Serializable {

  @Serial private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  @UuidGenerator
  @package.hibernate.constraint.UUID
  private UUID id;

  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "item")
  private Set<ForecastModel> forecasts;
}

But as I previously wrote, I don't have this forecasts field.
My problem is that one forecast can have up to more than ten thousand items, so what I need is that forecast brings just one forecast with the at most N items that comes from the Pageable spring-boot class.
This what I came up so far:
@Query(value = """
        FROM ForecastModel f
        JOIN FETCH f.item i
        JOIN FETCH i.clientTypeId ct
        JOIN FETCH i.itemProductId ip
        JOIN FETCH i.itemRegionId ir
        WHERE f.countryId.id = :countryId
        AND f.status = '1'
        AND f.chainId.id = (SELECT DISTINCT am.chain.id FROM AccountModel am WHERE am.vendorId = :vendorId and (am.accountId = :accountId OR am.vendorAccountId = :accountId OR am.beesAccountId = :accountId))
        AND i.month = :#{#params.period}
        AND (CAST(:#{#params.search} as text) IS NULL OR UPPER(ip.codeSku) LIKE %:#{#params.search}%
            OR UPPER(ip.description) LIKE %:#{#params.search}%
            OR UPPER(CAST(ip.ean as text)) LIKE %:#{#params.search}%)
        AND (CAST(:#{#params.type} as text) IS NULL OR ct.name = :#{#params.type})
        AND (CAST(:#{#params.region} as text) IS NULL OR ir.nameTarget = :#{#params.region})""", countProjection = "f.item")
Page<ForecastModel> getForecastList(@NotNull @Param("vendorId") UUID vendorId,
        @NotNull @Param("countryId") UUID countryId, @NotBlank @Param("accountId") String accountId,
        @NotNull @Param("params") GetForecastListRequestDTO params, @NotNull Pageable pageable);

But this query has two problems:

The first is that does not paginate by items, it is considering forecast, so if I have a forecast with ten thousand items it is fetching all of these; and

The second one is that for somehow is throwing a weird UnsupportedOperationException, here follows the stacktrace:
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.internal.PluralValuedSimplePathInterpretation.accept(PluralValuedSimplePathInterpretation.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.AbstractSqlAstTranslator.visitSortSpecification(AbstractSqlAstTranslator.java:3764)
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.AbstractSqlAstTranslator.visitSortSpecification(AbstractSqlAstTranslator.java:3745)
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.AbstractSqlAstTranslator.renderOrderBy(AbstractSqlAstTranslator.java:3351)
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.AbstractSqlAstTranslator.visitOrderBy(AbstractSqlAstTranslator.java:3335)
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.AbstractSqlAstTranslator.visitQuerySpec(AbstractSqlAstTranslator.java:3086)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLSqlAstTranslator.visitQuerySpec(PostgreSQLSqlAstTranslator.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.tree.select.QuerySpec.accept(QuerySpec.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.AbstractSqlAstTranslator.visitSelectStatement(AbstractSqlAstTranslator.java:988)
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.AbstractSqlAstTranslator.translateSelect(AbstractSqlAstTranslator.java:851)
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.AbstractSqlAstTranslator.translate(AbstractSqlAstTranslator.java:801)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.buildCacheableSqmInterpretation(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:372)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.withCacheableSqmInterpretation(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:268)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.performList(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:244)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.QuerySqmImpl.doList(QuerySqmImpl.java:518)
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractSelectionQuery.list(AbstractSelectionQuery.java:367)
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:119)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$PagedExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:204)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:92)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:149)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:137)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:136)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:120)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:164)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:143)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:70)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:391)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:244)
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy242.getForecastList(Unknown Source)
    at package.service.forecast.ForecastPostgreSQLService.getForecast(ForecastPostgreSQLService.java:55)
    at package.controller.forecast.ForecastController.getForecastList(ForecastController.java:43)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:751)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationInterceptor.invoke(MethodValidationInterceptor.java:141)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:751)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:703)
    at package.controller.forecast.ForecastController$$SpringCGLIB$$0.getForecastList(<generated>)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.lambda$doFilterInternal$3(FilterChainProxy.java:231)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$FilterObservation$SimpleFilterObservation.lambda$wrap$1(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:479)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$AroundFilterObservation$SimpleAroundFilterObservation.lambda$wrap$1(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:340)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator.lambda$wrapSecured$0(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:82)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:128)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$AroundFilterObservation$SimpleAroundFilterObservation.lambda$wrap$0(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:224)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.ServerHttpObservationFilter.doFilterInternal(ServerHttpObservationFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:340)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)



Thanks in advance for any help.

One challenge I can see here is, in one entity you have used List and in another Set. Either you should be using List in both the entities or Set. Set is recommended over List.

@JigneshM.Khatri, actually in ItemModel the relationship is not mapped, I just put for example purpose what I would have done, but I can't modify neither of these two classes, they are legacy code.
